# Pinning a specific python version in conda recipe

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm looking for a way to build a conda package which would use a specific python version.

According to the [issue submitted a while ago](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/2571) conda treats python in a special way, so simply putting

```
run:
    - python ==2.7.13 <build>
```

into `meta.yaml` won't work: conda will create a dependency on the latest release of 2.7 (`>=2.7,<2.8`) ignoring the minor version and build.

**Why?**

The [aforementioned issue](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/2571) suggests that pinning the python version is the wrong thing to do, but I really like the idea of my builds and deployments being reproducible. Running `conda create -n prod_env my_application=1.0.0` today should produce exactly the same environment as it did yesterday, including all dependencies and python version.

Comment: Could you just specify the python version for your environment? `conda create -n prod_env python=2.7.13 my_application=1.0.0`.

Comment: That would be a good backup option.


I don't want to use it as a primary solution, because my deployment scripts don't have an application version specified: it's just "install the latest version of my_application available". That makes releasing a new version as simple as pushing a new package into the channel. With python version being hardcoded in the scripts some part of this flexibility will be lost.

Comment: Hmmm, another option would be to containerize your build using something like Docker. This way you'd at least have reproducibility. Have you looked into that? I know it's not ideal since it would add a lot of weight to your application, but you'd at least have stability.